# Cocos2d CCProgressTimer image is not drawn. Why?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

Sorry in advance for newbie question, but after three days I need help. Could anybody help me?

I try to use `CCProgressTimer` for my class where I try to preload images for game into `CCTextureCache`. I tried to create the simplest code:

- Create `NSArray` with images' pathes.
- Add every image from that array and update the progress bar at the same time.

But my progress bar is not updated before becomes 100%. I added `NSLog` trace into `-(void)setPercentage:(float) percentage` and it looks like:

```
NSLog(@"percentage %f", percentage);
if(percentage_ != percentage) {
percentage_ = clampf( percentage, 0, 100);
[self updateProgress];
}
```

And I see messages for adding every image:

```
...
percentage 25
percentage 30
percentage 35
...
```

But the progress bar (the image) is updated only it becomes 100. I thought `[self updateProgress]` should update the progress image on every call of `setPercentage`.

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cocos2D's game loop works as follows:

1. update
2. draw
3. repeat from 1

Now you're very likely loading the textures in some sort of update method. That means it looks something like this:

- load texture 1
- update percentage
- load texture 2
- update percentage
- load texture 3
- update percentage
- load last texture
- update percentage to 100%
- draw progress timer

That means the progress timer isn't drawn until after all images are loaded. You can solve this by either loading the textures on a separate thread, or by allowing Cocos2D to render each update by scheduling a selector with interval 0, which means that selector will be run every frame:

```
-(id) init
{
  …
  [self scheduleUpdate:@selector(loadTexture) interval:0];
}

-(void) loadTexture
{
  if (no more textures)
  {
    [self unschedule:_cmd];
  }
  else
  {
    // load next texture
    // update progresstimer
  }
}
```

You will have to add the necessary variables to your class instance, most notably the progress timer and the index of the last texture that was loaded.